# Newton method and contraction map

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $a\in \mathbb{R}, \ a>0$. Show that applying Newton's method to the function $x^2-a$ gives the formula $x_{n+1}=\frac12(x_n+\frac{a}{x_n}).$ Prove that Newton's method works for any $x_0>0$ by showing that then $x_1\ge\sqrt{a}$ and the map sending $x$ into $\frac12(x+\frac{a}{x})$ is a contraction of $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\ge\sqrt{a}\}.$

I am pretty sure I know how to do the first part, but I don't know how to do the second part of the proof. By contraction it means, for a map $F$ of a metric space $E$ into itself there exists a real number $k<1$ such that $d(F(p),F(q))\le kd(p,q)$ for all $p,q\in E.$

Comment: Set $\sqrt{a} < b < c$.  Where does a single step send $(b,c)$?  Is the new interval longer or shorter?

Comment: Extra: Explore the expression $y_k=\frac{x_k-\sqrt{a}}{x_k+\sqrt a}$ and its iteration formula for $y_{k+1}$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part comes from evaluating the expression $x_{n+1} = x_n - { f(x_n) \over f'(x_n) }$.

Let $\phi(x) = {1 \over 2} (x + { a \over x})$. We have $\phi'(x) = {1 \over 2} (1 - { a \over x^2})$, and since $\lim_{x \to 0} \phi(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \phi(x) = \infty$, we see that $\phi$ has a minimum on $(0, \infty)$. Since the equation $\phi'(x) = 0$ has only one solution ($x= \sqrt{a}$), this must be the minimum and hence $\phi(x) \ge \phi(\sqrt{a}) = \sqrt{a}$.

It follows that if $x_{n+1} = \phi(x_n)$, then $x_{n+1} \ge \sqrt{a}$ for all $n$.

We also note that $\phi(x) = x$ **iff** $x = \sqrt{a}$.

If $x \ge \sqrt{a}$, we see that $0 \le \phi'(x) \le {1 \over 2}$, hence $\phi$ is a contraction on $[\sqrt{a}, \infty)$, and so has a unique fixed point, and the sequence generated by $x_{n+1} = \phi(x_n)$ converges to the unique fixed point of $\phi$.

Comment: Copper I have a quick question. How did you get that $\phi(\sqrt a)=\sqrt a$?

Comment: $\phi(\sqrt{a})= {1 \over 2} (\sqrt{a}+{ a \over \sqrt{a}} ) = {1 \over 2} (\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{a}) = \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: Copper, I am reviewing for a final and I am wondering, when you took $\lim_{x \to 0} \phi(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \phi(x) = \infty$ how did you conclude that $\phi$ has a minimum on $(0,\infty)?$

Comment: @user104235: The set $\{ x | \phi(x) \le \phi(1) \}$ is closed and bounded (otherwise this contradicts the limits being $\infty$), hence it is compact. A continuous function has a minimum and attains the minimum on a compact set.

Comment: Why exactly will that contradict the limits being $\infty$?

Comment: @user104235: You can prove it directly. You can choose some $M$ such that if $x >M$, then $\phi(x) > \phi(1)$, and some $m$ such that if $0<x<m$, then $\phi(x) > \phi(1)$, hence the set above must be contained in $[m,M]$, a bounded set.